# postMessage undefined error with dynamically added attribute

Tags: javascript, iframe, attributes, cross-domain, postmessage

I'm adding "**name=true**" attribute to iframe dynamically. Getting error "Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined"
  but its working fine on the console using same " window.iframe.true "

updated: "win" return undefined

```
<iframe src="crossdomain.com" id="iframe"></iframe>

<script>
    var win = window.iframe.nametrue;
    win.postMessage("statusPause", "othersite.com");
</script>
```

Comment: No, you're assigning an undefined value to `win` (as far as the posted code is concerned).

Comment: how to solve this issue, please help

Comment: Please take a careful look to your code. You're setting the value of `win` to `nametrue` of `iframe` in `window`. `nametrue` is not defined anywhere in the posted code, hence you're trying refer `undefined.postMessage`.

Comment: i'm  adding "name=true" attribute to iframe dynamically. on click event

Comment: That will just rename the iframe. You're still assigning the result to win variable. See Run ST's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot understand this "nametrue". However. This should at least solve the undefined issue.

```
var win = document.getElementById('iframe');
win.contentWindow.postMessage("statusPause", "othersite.com");
```

As you can see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage 
postMessage requires a valid target window. Your "window.iframe.nametrue" targeted nothing, and even if so. It is probably not the valid target window expected.
I got the iframe using the getElemenetById & called "contentWindow" on the iframe I got, this returns a valid targetWindow as required

Comment: document.getElementById('iframe'); its not working getting error : " win.postMessage is not a function "

Comment: Please re-read the answer, it tells you to call `win.contentWindow.postMessage` ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign attribute `name="nametrue"` before assigning the win to the iframe.